# How to use a LINQ query to get XElement values when XElements have same name

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a piece of xml like the following:

```
<Table>
  <Record>
    <Field>Value1_1</Field>
    <Field>Value1_2</Field>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Field>Value2_1</Field>
    <Field>Value2_2</Field>
  </Record>
</Table>
```

What i would like is a LINQ query that generates an IEnumerable that i can assign as the datasource of a DataGrid. What i have so far is as follows:

```
var temp = from record in table.Elements("Record")
            select record.Element("Field").Value
```

The fact that I can have multiple field elements is my stumbling block.

In the above example, what i need is something like an `IEnumerable<string,string>`.
The datagrid would look something like this:

```
Value1_1, Value1_2
Value2_1, Value2_2
```

Comment: The XML is a bit strange can we assume that each field element within a record in fact as a unique name.  They surely aren't all called 'Field' are they?

Comment: What is your expected behavior?  I.e. given that there are multiple Field elements, which one do you want?

Comment: The xml is strange right enough but unfortunately I'm stuck with it.

Comment: DSO I've updated the question with the expected behavior.

Comment: Perhaps update the question again with a valid type -- `IEnumerable<string,string>` is not it. I used `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` in my answer, but perhaps you want `string[,]` or `string[][]` or `MyRows<MyColumns>`, etc.

Answer (score 11):

Would something like this help?

```
var a = from record in table.Elements("Record")
    select new
    {
        one = (string)record.Elements().ElementAt(0),
        two = (string)record.Elements().ElementAt(1)
    };
```

Comment: Agreed - I think this is his only option given that the order of them matters.  Could be made better (more exact) by putting "Field" in the empty Elements() call.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for when this question came up in my search, I created the bounty to reward you for this since it doesn't look like the asker was going to accept...

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to denormalize the field so that it fits in 1 column in your data grid.

Does the following help?

```
var table = XElement.Parse(@"<Table>
                                <Record><Field>Value1_1</Field><Field>Value1_2</Field></Record>
                                <Record><Field>Value2_1</Field><Field>Value2_2</Field></Record>
                             </Table>");


var temp = from record in table.Elements("Record")
           from field in record.Elements("Field")
           group field.Value by record into groupedFields
           select groupedFields.Aggregate((l, r) => l + ", " + r);

foreach (var row in temp)
    Console.WriteLine(row);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Disclaimer: I don't do much SQL or LINQ anymore, so this probably could be made better. Feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what the problem is and why a number of these answers look so complicated :-/ Here is my offering:

```
var r = (from record in table.Elements("Record")
         select (from element in record.Elements("Field")
                 select element.Value));

// => IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>
```

The inner IEnumerable is for the columns and the outer is for the rows. (The question is kind of confusing because there is no `IEnumerable<T,T'>`, the above is my adaptation of the intent.)

You could make the inner IEnumerable into a string (e.g. Join on ", "), but that's not very fun to put into a grid if you mean the values as columns!

```
var r = (from record in table.Elements("Record")
         select String.Join(", ",
             record.Elements("Field").Select(f => f.Value).ToArray());

// => IEnumerable<string>
```

The above could likely be made nicer if I actually knew LINQ Expressions. However, it works and covers the "other" case -- the "ToArray" is for .NET 3.5 and below.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

[TestMethod]
    public void Linq_XElement_Test()
    {


    string xml = @"<Table>
  <Record>
    <Field>Value1_1</Field>
    <Field>Value1_2</Field>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Field>Value2_1</Field>
    <Field>Value2_2</Field>
  </Record>
</Table>";

    XElement elements = XElement.Parse(xml);

    var qryRecords = from record in elements.Elements("Record")
                  select record;

    foreach (var rec in qryRecords)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(rec.Value);
    }

    var qryFields = from record in elements.Elements("Record")
                 from fields in record.Elements("Field")
                 select fields;

    foreach (var fil in qryFields)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(fil.Value);
    }

    IEnumerable<string> list = qryFields.Select(x => x.Value);

    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: Please state what your posted code does to solve the problem. Your code may help, but stating what it does may help other people to understand and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain calls to `Elements()`:

```
var temp = from field in table.Elements("Record").Elements("Field")
           select field.Value;
```

You can also use `Descendants()`:

```
 var temp = from field in table.Descendants("Field")
            select field.Value;
```

However, this will return all <Field> elements under <Table>, even if they are not within a <Record> element.

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off in what you're looking for, but are you looking for something like this?

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Records DS");
        ds.Tables.Add("Records");
        foreach (XElement record in table.Descendants("Record"))
        {
            var temp = from r in record.Descendants("Field")
                       select r.Value;

            string[] datum = temp.ToArray();
            if (datum != null
                && datum.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string s in datum)
                    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add();
                DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = datum;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

Then return `ds` and set the `DataMember` to `"Records"`

Answer (score 0):

You need a 2-step processs:

Annotate the records (in lieu of attributes) and then
Enumerate the fields and pass the values into an anonymous class for binding, like so:

```
string xml = [string-goes-here];

  XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xml);

  int count= 0;
  foreach(XElement recordElems in elem.Elements("Record")){
    recordElems.SetAttributeValue("id", count);
    count++;
  }
  var temp = from record in elem.Elements("Record")
             from field in record.Elements("Field")
             select new { Record = "Record " + record.Attribute("id").Value, Field = field.Value };

  foreach (var item in temp)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Record, item.Field);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Er... I think you're using the wrong LINQ paradigm for this problem.  You should be using LINQ to XML which is slightly different maybe than you're expecting.

Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx

It explains it using a structurally similar example to the one you presented.

Answer (score 0):

Would an

```
IEnumerable<List<string>>
```

work? (not sure how to get that to display inline)

```
var recordList = from record in data.Elements("record") select record;
List<List<string>> x = new List<List<string>>(recordList.Count());
foreach (var record in recordList)
{
  var z = from field in record.Elements("field") select field.Value;
  x.Add(z.ToList());
}
return x.AsEnumerable();
```

Don't know if that works for your specific scenario or not.

Answer (score 0):

var detail1 = from d in ds.tbl_Looking_Fors
                             where d.Profile_ID == id 
                             select d.Looking_For ;

```
            string[] datum = detail1.ToArray();
            if (datum != null && datum.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in datum)
                {
                    Label6.Text = datum[0]+" , "+datum[1];
                }

            }
```