# C# xml to linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm still struggling with the XML to Linq syntax.

I have a XML-structure where I'm trying to query the different prices of a product.

This is the XML:

```
  <product>
    <description>productname</description>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <key>RetailPrice</key>
        <value>100.00 $</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <key>StockPrice</key>
        <value>80.00 $</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </product>
```

There is a big amount of `<product>` in the XML-file so I'm trying to query the price of a specific productname.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: There are multiple prices for a product, which one you want? If you want all, in what format?

Comment: Show what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `XElement` class. Look at the related post: [How to use a LINQ query to get XElement values when XElements have same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890313/how-to-use-a-linq-query-to-get-xelement-values-when-xelements-have-same-name).

Do something like:

```
string[] prices = xml.Elements("product")
.Where(x => x.Element("description").Value == productName)
.Element("properties")
.Elements("property")
.Where(x => x.Element("key").Value == "RetailPrice")
.Select(x => x.Element("value").Value)
.ToArray();
```

You could do additional null checking with C# 6 null-propagation operator.

```
string[] prices = xml.Elements("product")
.Where(x => x.Element("description")?.Value == productName)
.Element("properties")
.Elements("property")
.Where(x => x.Element("key")?.Value == "RetailPrice")
.Select(x => x.Element("value").Value)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: You're not filtering on the productname.

Comment: Could you explain me what the ?. does?

Comment: It is not completely necessary (you could write the code with only `.`). It checks whether the result is `null`. If the result of the function is `null`, it returns `null`, otherwise it returns the `Value` property of the result. It is the null-propagation operator from C# 6: http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/.

Comment: @IgorŠevo you shoud note that this will **only work in Visual Studio 2015**. It would be much better to modify the code so that c# 3.0 onwards can run it