# C# XML XDocument Parsing) How to know the name of specific ancestor node with specific value of grandchild?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, find

I've tried couples of hours but there's no specific solution for me.
XML Parsing and LINQ are complicated to me..

Can anybody help me to know the name of specific ancestor node which include its grandchild with specific value?

There are R1, R2, R3, R4...and I want to know which R has the B7 grandchild having value 201404418

And in my case, the names of ancestors are not repeatedly same but have number variable to be identified.

Furthermore, to utilize the already downloaded XDocument object and for efficient performance, please advise with XDocument only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RESULT>
    <ITEM>
        <R1>
            <B DESC="product">
                <B1> chocolate </B1>
                <B2> white </B2>
                <B3> Kisses </B3>
                <B4> bar type </B4>
                <B5> 2 $ </B5>
                <B6>2014-09-26 </B6>
                <B7>201404418 </B7>
            </B>
            <C DESC="ingredient">
                <CR1>
                    <C1>cacao paste </C1>
                    <C2> concentrated </C2>
                    <C3> 21.69 </C3>
                    <C4> gram </C4>
                </CR1>
                <CR2>
                    <C1> strawberry cream </C1>
                    <C2> normal </C2>
                    <C3> 10 </C3>
                    <C4> gram </C4>
                </CR2>
                <CR3>
                    <C1> almond &amp; nut </C1>
                    <C2> dried product </C2>
                    <C3> 10 </C3>
                    <C4> gram </C4>
                </CR3>
            </C>
            <D DESC="basic informations of product">
                <D1>http://food.tfda.go.tn/html/bxmPdfViewer.jsp?docid=145977782405945000134</D1>
                <D2>http://food.tfda.go.tn/html/bxmPdfViewer.jsp?docid=145971282405945000164</D2>
                <D3>http://food.tfda.go.tn/html/bxmPdfViewer.jsp?docid=145979082424311500014</D3>
                <D6>http://www.food.tn/images/insert_pdf/IN_2014091700002_00.pdf</D6>
            </D>
            <E DESC="storage">
                <E1> room temperature </E1>
                <E2> 36 months from manufacturing date </E2>
                <E5> in-house packaging unit </E5>
                <E6> 1 $/unit </E6>
            </E>
            <F DESC="production record">
                <FR1>
                    <F1>2014</F1>
                    <F2>0</F2>
                    <F3>0</F3>
                    <F4>0</F4>
                    <F5>161,816</F5>
                    <F7>161,816</F7>
                </FR1>
                <FR2>
                    <F1>2015</F1>
                    <F2>469,591</F2>
                    <F3>466,147</F3>
                    <F4>473,315</F4>
                    <F5>612,964</F5>
                    <F7>2,022,017</F7>
                </FR2>
            </F>
            <G DESC="import record"></G>
        </R1>
    </ITEM>
</RESULT>
```

Comment: Do you have some code so far? Did you try  to look into `XDocument` documentation and other post related?

Comment: As mentioned, I've tried research couples of hour and analyzed other posts. The one I tried is of LINQ but I'm extremely not familiar to customize even similar case. Can you guide some way?

Comment: And selectnode seems not belong to XDocument.

Comment: Be careful before downvoting. If then, why not get some exising answer link as duplicate. My case is different that the parent names have their number variable to be identified.

Comment: *I want to know which R has the B7 child having value 201404418*, So in this case the answer supposed to be string "R1"?

Comment: Btw, *parent* of B7 is B. R1 is *ancestor*. Learn the terms so that you can explain better, and understand articles/tutorials about XML parsing easier

Comment: Yes, in this case the answer is supposed to be "R1". I'll try to learn whatever needed..But I already spent too much time on development and have to care everything all alone and finish as soon as possible and get back to the usual life...This application will be freely distributed in our country.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? It seems that you have accepted an answer, which would indicate that you regard it as solved.

Comment: @halfer, Thanks for your comment. As you know, somebody provided the solution. Do you think this topic is too broad and there're already too many same questions and answers? It seems there's bad etiquette and violence by few people who don't respect others. How can we protect our rights? and fight against this bad democracy?

Comment: @halfer, Mr. halfer, Before you're saying I need to roll back, what is your opinion? Do you also think the topic of my question is too broad and there're too many same questions and answers? You say I just need to wait. The addition in my question is a not complaint, it's my opinion. Without a opinion, how can I can prevent my question is deleted by violence of indiscreete people who didn't think about my problem for even 3 minutes? Some guy also made my question on hold because it's exact duplicate but I told him my opinion and he rolled back the on hold on my question.

Comment: @halfer, I don't care reputation, don't want to be king of stackoverflow. I just want to protect my rights. Thanks for the flag and if moderators(stackoverflow) re-open my question back, I'll surely roll back my opinion. I'll see how the system of stackoverflow works.

Comment: @KayLee: Please do not edit rants into your post. Editing your question to show what code you have tried, will result in it being reopened. Editing your post to add a rant, will not.

Comment: @Matt, I didn't edit rant into my post but tried efforts to follow the instruction from stackoverflow to specify my original question more. And the addition was my opinion. I don't care my question to be re-opened but I want to keep my rights and don't like people who lack of carefullness and don't respect others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `Linq` to `Xml`, look for element with matching criteria and grab it's `Parent`

```
    XDocument doc =  XDocument.Load(filename);

    var parent = doc.Descendants()  
                    .Elements("B7") // look for element
                    .FirstOrDefault(x=>(string)x.Value == "201404418")
                    .Parent; // Parent.
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KJLwVp)

Comment: I tried your suggestion first because of using XDocument but got NullReferenceException..And wehn I ran the demo of Fiddle, no console window was opened..Many thanks for your guide. Can you guide me more?

Comment: When did you get null reference exception? fiddle will not open a console, but you can see the output at the bottom. Try noticing the ouput, it prints `B`.

Comment: Oh, I can see 'B'. However, I need to know the name of parent of 'B' like R1, R2, R3. I mean R with numbers.

Comment: Then just do the parent again on element B, so look for `.Parent.Parent`

Comment: hmm..still NullReferenceException..Your demo works fine but why not this case..? I think because .Parent is Null, .Parent.Parent might be Null..

Comment: Is it failing in fiddle or in your code?

Comment: Failing in my code. But oh, my goodness..after changing to .Parent.Parent in your fiddle, 'R1' is showing..Maybe I have to look deeply into for the difference..

Comment: I suggest try trimming your comparision, like `x.Value.Trim() == "201404418"`. I suspect there might be spaces which causing the issue.

Comment: Oh, The problem is solved..! Thank you so much..I needed to change the number to be compared because I used different number in real testing just confused in taking yesterday's XML code..And finally, by parent.Name, I got 'R1'. Also, as a useful advice, trimming will be what I will need in real development. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

This will help you with `troubleshooting` your problem and hopefully solving the issue.

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<record>
  <R1>
       <B DESC="product">
            <B1> chocolate </B1>
            <B2> white </B2>
            <B3> Kisses </B3>
            <B4> bar type </B4>
            <B5> 2 $ </B5>
            <B6>2014-09-26 </B6>
            <B7>201404418 </B7>
        </B>
  </R1>
</record>
```

Something like this should get you to the right path;

```
//Parse XML to XElement
var xmlObject = XElement.Parse(TypeOfBill2014); 

var result = xmlObject.Elements("B")
                 .Where(x => (string)x.Element("B7") == 201404418)
                 .Select(x => x.Parent)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here are some links for;

- [How to Start with XML and LINQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400269/How-to-Start-with-XML-and-LINQ-A-Beginner-Guide)
- MSDN [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx)
- A SO [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890313/how-to-use-a-linq-query-to-get-xelement-values-when-xelements-have-same-name)

For some further reading.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent knowledge. But, could you suggest more precisely as described in the post like R1, R2. The names include number variable..

Comment: @KayLee using the above example, you should be able to get the parent of any element you are looking for - try it out, and see what parent it returns. From there manipulate it to get anything else you need. This should be all you need.

Comment: I need to utilize already downloaded object of XDocument. I tried but It seems I have to convert XDocument object to XElement object?

Comment: As you've noticed by now, using `Hari Prasad's` solution will work for you with XDocument, (this is the same, but working with XElement object) to get the same result with the above code, you could do the same (i.e. search for Parent.Parent). Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your valuable answer !